# Get File Extension of openFileDialog C#

Tags: c#

I need help with some code:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName) == "wav")
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path + "/convert/WAV2ADX.exe "; // the path to the wav2adx file
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = '"' + ofd.FileName + '"' + " " + '"' + textBox1.Text + "/" + songName + ".adx" + '"'; // Arguments

    File.Delete(textBox1.Text + "/" + songName + ".adx"); // Deleting File

    myProcess.Start();
}
```

is not working, what am i doing wrong? ofd is my openFileDialog.

Greetings Chris.

Comment: Do you just want the extension of a file from open file dialog ?

Comment: What's not working? What errors are you getting? What do you expect to happen, that isn't happening?

Comment: _"is not working"_ what's not working? what errors are you getting?

Comment: "is not working" is not working well as an error description. What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Any error messages (which and at which line)? Any exceptions (message and stack trace please)?

Comment: @zackraiyan basicly yes and i want to use it in a 
if query

Comment: Assuming you are picking a `.wav` file, your command ends up being `myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\some\path\to\my.wav /convert/WAV2ADX.exe ";` Do you see why that won't work?

Comment: @TJWolschon Nothing is happening, im getting no error's its not giving any results

Comment: it's ".wav" as can be read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please, if you want to keep on programming, learn how to **debug** your code. Putting the result of `Path.GetExtension()` into a variable, setting a breakpoint, et voila, you see what's wrong yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The extension of the specified path **(including the period ".")**, or null, or String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns null. If path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns String.Empty.

Your code

```
if (Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName) == "wav")
```

should be

```
if (".wav".Equals(Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Because you want to include the period **and** you want a case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName) == "wav")
```

to

```
if (Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName) == ".wav")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx

^^ has the details for what the `GetExtension` method returns